# apache2 ssl not working

Tags: apache, ssl, sles

Evening,

I have SLES 12 installed with Apache2 running.
All modules I need are installed but can't seem to get ssl working.
Firewall is turned off since the webserver is behind a Citrix NetScaler.
Port 80 is working fine and it also seems that apache is listening on port 443, but as soon as I try to reach the website on 443, the browser just keeps loading.
When I point the website direct to the server (in my hostfile, so it's not via the NetScaler), I get this error message:

ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

When I look at the listeners:

```
# netstat -tulpn| grep :443
tcp        0      0 :::443     :::*    LISTEN      23270/httpd2-prefor
# netstat -tulpn| grep :80
tcp        0      0 :::80    :::*      LISTEN      23270/httpd2-prefor
```

What could cause this?

Don't know if this info is valuable but when I go to my site:
http://example.com:443

It gives me a 403 error stating I'm not allowed to go there or there is no index.html, index.php etc.....

Comment: telnet to 443 from remote side shows connection refused, timeout, or connection closed?

Comment: @ssnobody Putty telnet on port 443 says: "Network error: Software caused connection abort". But I'm guessing that's because of the NetScaler since another website behind that same NetScaler (but different webserver) gives the same error but SSL works fine on that website.